# Removing unwanted tags from picasa

Tags: batch, picasa, tags

Before Picasa added its face finding feature I had tagged a lot of photos with names of people. Now I want to remove all these tags is there any easy way to view all teh tags currently in use by photos in Picasa, and to be able to remove a given tag from all photos that have it?